# How interrupting a long processing by touching?

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin

I needed to program a way that that would allow the user to interrupt my long processing, if desired by user, by touching a particular button.

Therefore I needed 2 threads, one running my  long process and another waiting user interaction, if he wanted to interrupt

From all I read, I understood that the best solution for me would be *coroutines*

However, I has never used *coroutines* in *Kotlin* before. So I am layman in that feature.

To be honest, none of the tutorials in Internet was clear enough to me.
With difficulty, I was able to do something.

This below code is inside button `btRunOrStop` click handling and it is working OK, with some changes from standard:

```
  if (! solved)   // Stopping the long process
    bStat.setText("")  // clearing the progress 
    solving = false
    runBlocking { jobGl.cancelAndJoin()} // Cancel and ends my long process.
  } else {    // Starting the long process
    bStat.setText("Solving ...") // static progress 
    GlobalScope.launch {          
      try {
      solving = true   // Warn that the long process is running
      jobGl  = async {
        runningProcess(param)   // Finally my rocket was launched
      } 
      retGl = jobGl.await()  // return of my process, after running OK
      solved = true          // warn that the process has ended OK.
      solving = false        // No more pending process
  // Generate an artificial button touch
      mEv = MotionEvent.obtain(x,y,MotionEvent.ACTION_UP,0F,0F,0)
  // False click to post processing after process OK.
      btRunOrStop.dispatchTouchEvent(mEv)  
     }
     finally{}  // Exception handing. It does not  work.
    }
   }
   else { code after successful execution}
```

Finally my long process:

```
suspend fun solveEquac(param:Double):Double {
  ..... if (! solving) return ......
  ..... if (! GlobalScope.isActive) return ...  // It does not work.
}
```

Unfortunately, I was required to use a variable (`solving`) instead of using `isActive` or exception block, (`try finally`) which is recommended by official *Kotlin* documentation, because it just don't work. The process stops, but only after it's over.

My questions:

**1)** Is it possible a memory leakage by using `GlobalScope` in same activity?

**2)** If yes, in what condition it can occurs?

**3)** If yes, how can I avoid it?

**4)** Why exception handling (`try finally`) or `isActive` does not work?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should avoid GlobalScope as it will make it clumsy to cancel jobs and prevent leaks. It is a singleton so it will outlive your Activity. The leak occurs because your `launch` lambda is capturing a reference to your Activity by using properties of your Activity.

As a side note, `isActive` is always true on your GlobalScope because you never canceled your GlobalScope, only one of its child jobs. And you likely wouldn't want to cancel GlobalScope if you were using it for more than one job at a time.

One of the easiest ways to use CoroutineScope is to attach it to your Activity as a delegate, so your Activity is its own scope, allowing you to directly call `launch`. You just need to remember to cancel it in `onDestroy()` so jobs won't outlive your Activity. (At least not by long, as long as you make your jobs cancellable--see below.)

```
class MyActivity: AppCompatActivity(), CoroutineScope by MainScope() {
    //...
    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        cancel() // cancel any jobs in this Activity's scope
    }
}
```

Best practice is to always make your `suspend` functions internally select the correct dispatcher for their operation. To make your suspend function cancellable, it must be something with exit points in it, which are usually calls to cancellation-checking suspend functions (like `yield()` and `delay()` and functions of your own that call them). You can alternatively check `isActive` and return early if its false, which makes your function *cancellable* but  usable like `yield()` to exit another suspend function. So if there is a big for-loop, you can call `yield()` in the loop to give it an exit point. Or if there are a bunch of sequential steps, put `yield()` calls in between. The alternative is to keep checking the state of `isActive`, which is a property of the context so you can just directly reference it from within your `withContext` block.

```
// Just an example. You'll have to come up with a way to break up your calculation.
suspend fun solveEquation(param:Double): Double = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
    val x = /** some calculation */
    yield()
    val y = /** some calculation with x */
    yield()
    var z = /** some calculation with y */
    for (i in 0..1000) {
        yield()
        z += /** some calculation */
    }
    z
}
```

I'm not sure what you were trying to do with `try/finally`. You just need to use those as you normally would when working with streams. You can put a `yield()` inside the `try` or `use` block and be confident the `finally` block will execute regardless of cancellation.

To make your job cancellable, I suggest using a variable that's null when it's not runnable:

```
var calcJob: Job? = null // Accessed only from main thread.
```

Then your button listener can be something like this:

```
btRunOrStop.onClickListener = {
    // Cancel job if it's running. 
    // Don't want to join it because that would block the main thread.
    calcJob?.let {
        bStat.setText("")
        it.cancel()
        calcJob = null
    } ?: run { // Create job if one didn't exist to cancel
        calcJob = launch { // Called on the Activity scope so we're in the main UI thread.
            bStat.setText("Solving ...")
            mEv = MotionEvent.obtain(x,y,MotionEvent.ACTION_UP,0F,0F,0)
            btRunOrStop.dispatchTouchEvent(mEv)
            // You might want to check this doesn't trigger the onClickListener and
            // create endless loop. (I don't know if it does.)

            val result = solveEquation(someParam) // background calculation
            // Coroutine resumes on main thread so we can freely work with "result"
            // and update UI here.

            calcJob = null // Mark job as finished.
        }
    }
}
```

So by following the practice of using `= withContext(Dispatchers.Default /*or IO*/){}` to define your suspend functions, you can safely do sequential UI stuff everywhere else and the code in your `launch` block will be very clean.

Comment: I will try follow your wise advices.  However, my app is a single activity app. I've created all my screens and views programmatically without XML, using custom dialogs. Do you believe in memory leakage even so?

Comment: Not sure what the XML has to do with it. If you activity is destroyed, but some longer-living object is still referencing it, it will leak. Even though you have a single-Activity app, when you exit your Activity, the Application itself is not immediately killed, so if the Activity leaks, your dead one will still be taking up memory. If the user then opens your app again, there are now two activities, even though one is dead. And if this happens repeatedly, you will have several concurrent leaked Activities.

Comment: Whether this is really a problem is up to you. Maybe even if your job is not cancelled, you are still sure it will finish within one second. Then your leaked activity will be cleaned up after one second, so maybe it's OK to leak it temporarily. You certainly wouldn't want to do this with network operations though, because their life is unpredictable. But the only advantage of GlobalScope is to save you a couple lines of code to create a local Activity Scope. Why engage in a bad practice on this simple project just because you can?

Comment: I agree with you, of course. It's just a curiosity.

Comment: I've tested your suggestions.  `CoroutineScope by MainScope()` and `cancel()` in `destroy` works, but `isActive()` or `mainScope().isActive()` keeps on returning true. `Yield` just can be used inside a suspension function, however I use nested functions in my processing. When I put all as suspensed functiions, the compiler gives an internal error.

Comment: Finally, I try to use exception block in my thread processing, because it's a direct recommendation of official Kotlin documentation.

`Closing resources with finally`section in 
[kotlin - coroutines - Cancelation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/cancellation-and-timeouts.html)

Comment: Your nested functions should also be suspend functions that use `= withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {}`. Then they can also call `yield()` so they are cancellable. Not sure why `isActive` never turns false for you--would have to see the code. The exception block examples you linked are just showing *how* to use exception blocks. They are nonsense examples with `delay` calls to simulate IO actions like file operations, where you would *need* a try/catch. In actual practice there's no reason to put a try/catch around `println()` and `delay()` calls.